# Uploading PNG File (HTTP POST) with C++ Winsock API

Tags: c++, file-upload, http-post, winsock2

I'm trying to upload a PNG file through Winsock2 HTTP Post. Here's my request string:

```
boundary = "-----rueldotme";                                                                
request += "POST " + uri + " HTTP/1.1\r\n";                                     
request += "Host: " + hostname + "\r\n";
request += "User-Agent: " + UserAgent + "\r\n";
request += "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n";
request += "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5\r\n";
request += "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate\r\n";
request += "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\r\n";
request += "Keep-Alive: 115\r\n";
request += "Connection: keep-alive\r\n";
request += "Content-Length: " + fileSize + "\r\n";
request += "Content-Type: multipart/form-data, boundary=" + boundary + "\r\n";
request += "\r\n";
request += "--" + boundary + "\r\n";
request += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filename\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"\r\n";
request += "Content-Type: image/png; charset=binary\r\n";
request += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n";
request += "\r\n";
request += "%s\r\n";
request += "\r\n";
```

The connection is OK, no errors and such, the `fileCon` by the way is from `ReadFile()`. And there's no error code. The number of bytes read is the same as the output of `GetFileSize()`. I tried displaying the contents of `fileCon` but only gave me this:

[image]

Don't mind the title "*Error*" (I set it).

Also, the request takes ages to complete, and gives me a blank response. Yep, blank with no HTTP headers. Am I doing the request right? Should I really have to include the file contents at the POST data?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: The PNG size is about 256KB. I'm in a 1mbps connection.

**EDIT**: Sorry if the information was insufficient. Anyway, here's what I did lately:

```
int flz;
char bdata[BSIZE];
DWORD dwe, bytesRead = 0;
HANDLE fh = CreateFile(fileName.c_str(), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);  
LPVOID fbuff = NULL;
flz = GetFileSize(fh, NULL);
fbuff = malloc(flz);
ReadFile(fh, fbuff, flz, &bytesRead, NULL));

...

sprintf_s(bdata, BSIZE, request.c_str(), reinterpret_cast<char *>(fbuff)); //BSIZE = 1024

...

send(sock, bdata, std::strlen(bdata), 0);
```

Comment: i think may be problem is there in the reading the PNG image file content.

Comment: You need to store the binary content in the char* not in the string

Comment: It doesn't matter AFAIK. Besides my buffer is LPVOID and I just converted it to std::string. I don't see a problem there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not enough information to solve the problem, so I'll give a meta-answer instead:
Use a packet sniffer (e.g., [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)) to check exactly what data is actually being sent and received. This will let you verify that the request is as it should be, and that the "blank response" you're getting really is blank.

One wild stab in the dark:
You haven't included any variable declarations in your code snippet, so I don't know what type "fileCon" is, but don't forget that the PNG data is likely to contain null bytes, which will mess up a default conversion from a `char*` to a `std::string`.

**Edit:**
Your modification contains the same bug that the `std::string` based version had, namely, that the PNG data is likely to contain null bytes. Perhaps this code will explain more clearly:

```
const char* data = "Hello\0world."; // some data that contains a null byte
std::string dataStr(data);
std::cout << dataStr << "\n"; // will print "Hello".
std::cout << dataStr.size() << "\n"; // will print "5"
char buf[512];
sprintf_s(buf, sizeof(buf), "Data: %s\n", data);
std::cout << buf; // will print "Data: Hello"
```

Both the conversion to `std::string` and formatting with `sprintf` will interpret the null byte as being the end of the data, and so the rest of the original data (`"world."`) will never be used.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, and I've edited my question. I used LiveHTTPHeaders to build those header lines. And I'm now using a `char *` variable to hold the request string.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. I was wondering, how could I pass the `char *` buffer with the file contents, and the string `request` in `send()`.